# How do I tab to next element without using tabindex=0?

Tags: jquery, focus

**Significant SOLUTION at end**

How do I tab to next element without using `tabindex=0`?

If I programmatically say:

```
$currentElement = $(document.activeElement);
$nextElement = $currentElement.next();
$nextElement.focus();
```

within a `keydown` callback function, why do I still need `tabindex=0`?

As long as I call `.focus()`, why doesn't the browser effectively jump to that element?

**ADDITION HERE**:

I now realize that `tabindex=0` is crucial for a Browser to tab to the next element. With that now in the forefront, I need a different approach:

1. Only with a `keyup` Event does a Browser actually tab to the next element with `tabindex=0` and give it the **new** focus!
2. As opposed to actually tabbing to next element with a `keydown` Event. Currently, the focused item remains as it was with the `keydown` Event and will change to the next `tabindex=0` **only** with `keyup`.

This is the crux of my challenge because I need to tab with `keydown` and not wait for `keyup`.

How can I make that happen?

**SOLVED!**

EG, when a keydown handler sees my pressed Tab key, I want this keydown handler to create a keyup event and send this Tab keypress to the browser so that my keyup handler is executed

```
$(.elem).keydown {

// create keyup Event and send this event to
// browser which will then execute my keyup handler

}

$(.elem).keyup {

   // sent here

}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
$(.elem).keydown {

    $(.elem).trigger("keyup");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like One-Time-Password input? When you input something in the first input element and focus will jump to the next input. Here I made a sample for your reference:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-class">
    <input class="input-class" />
    <input class="input-class" />
    <input class="input-class" />
    <input class="input-class" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.input-class').keyup(function () {
if ($(this).val() !== "") {
    //checking function logic here
    $(this).next().focus();
}
})
```